# Cocoa NSArray/NSSet: -makeObjectsPerformSelector: vs. fast enumeration

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I want to perform the same action over several objects stored in a `NSSet`.

My first attempt was using a fast enumeration:

```
for (id item in mySetOfObjects)
    [item action];
```

which works pretty fine. Then I thought of:

```
[mySetOfObjects makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(action)];
```

And now, I don't know what is the best choice. As far as I understand, the two solutions are equivalent. But are there arguments for preferring one solution over the other?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would argue for using `makeObjectsPerformSelector`, since it allows the NSSet object to take care of its own indexing, looping and message dispatching. The people who wrote the NSSet code are most likely to know the best way to implement that particular loop.

At worst, they would simply implement the exact same loop, and all you gain is slightly cleaner code (no need for the enclosing loop). At best, they made some internal optimizations and the code will actually run faster.

The topic is briefly mentioned in Apple's [Code Speed Performance](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/performance/Conceptual/CodeSpeed/Articles/CriticalCode.html) document, in the section titled "Unrolling Loops".

If you're concerned about performance, the best thing to do is set up a quick program which performs some selector on the objects in a set. Have it run several million times, and time the difference between the two different cases.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I didn't know this document! As you say, the section "Unrolling loops" clearly states that Cocoa developers have made internal optimizations with -makeObjectsPerformSelector:

Comment: My pleasure. There's some interesting stuff in there.

Answer (score 7):

I too was presented with this question. I find in the Apple docs "Collections Programming Topics" under "[Sets: Unordered Collections of Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Sets.html)" the following:

> The NSSet method objectEnumerator lets
>   you traverse elements of the set one
>   by one. And
>   themakeObjectsPerformSelector: and
>   makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:
>   methods provide for sending messages
>   to individual objects in the set. In
>   most cases, fast enumeration should be
>   used because it is faster and more
>   flexible than using an NSEnumerator or
>   the makeObjectsPerformSelector:
>   method. For more on enumeration, see
>   “Enumeration: Traversing a
>   Collection’s Elements.”

This leads me to believe that Fast Enumeration is still the most efficient means for this application.

Answer (score 4):

I would not use makeObjectsPerformSelector for the simple reason that it is the kind of call that you don't see all that often. Here is why for example - I need to add debugging code as the array is enumerated, and you really can't do that with makeObjectsPerformSelector unless you change how the code works in Release mode which is a real no no.

```
for (id item in mySetOfObjects)
{
    #if MY_DEBUG_BUILD
    if ([item isAllMessedUp])
        NSLog(@"we found that wily bug that has been haunting us"); 
    #endif

    [item action];
}
```

--Tom

Answer (score 2):

`makeObjectsPerformSelector:` might be slightly faster, but I doubt there's going to be any practical difference 99% of the time. It is a bit more concise and readable though, I would use it for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

If pure speed is the only issue (i.e. you're creating some rendering engine where every tiny CPU cycle counts), the fastest possible way to iterate through any of the NSCollection objects (as of iOS 5.0 ~ 6.0) is the various "enumerateObjectsUsingBlock" methods.  I have no idea why this is, but I tested it and this seems to be the case...

I wrote small test creating collections of hundreds of thousands of objects that each have a method which sums a simple array of ints.  Each of those collections were forced to perform the various types of iteration (for loop, fast enumeration, makeObjectsPerformSelector, and enumerateObjectsUsingBlock) millions of times, and in almost every case the "enumerateObjectsUsingBlock" methods won handily over the course of the tests.

The only time when this wasn't true was when memory began to fill up (when I began to run it with *millions* of objects), after which it began to lose to "makeObjectsPerformSelector".

I'm sorry I didn't take a snapshot of the code, but it's a very simple test to run, I highly recommend giving it a try and see for yourself.  :)