# How to check if an NSMutableArray contains an object which contains certain text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

How can I check if an NSMutableArray contains an object which contains certain text? Then, if there is one piece of text which has been found, it will replace it with another bit of text.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
@interface NSMutableArray (JRAdditions) 

- (void) replaceStringObjectsContainingString:(NSString *) str withString:(NSString *) newString;

@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (JRAdditions)

- (void) replaceStringObjectsContainingString:(NSString *) str withString:(NSString *) newString {

   for(unsigned i = 0; i < [self count]; ++i) {
      id obj = [self objectAtIndex:i];

      if(![obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) continue;

      NSString *replaced = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:str withString:newString];
      [self replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:replaced];

   }
}

@end
```

You'd then use it as such:

```
NSMutableArray *array = ...;

[array replaceStringObjectsContainingString:@"blah" withString:@"foo"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a check inside a for loop for all objects in the NSMutableArray , use
[object rangeOfString:@"text"] for check the range.

Answer (score -1):

You can either iterate on your array, do the checking on each object and then replace if necessary.

Or you could use something fancier with :

```
- (void)makeObjectsPerformSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject
```

I havent tried it but you could create a method in your object that takes a dictionary, or an array with first element being the text to compare and second element the text to replace :

```
- (void) replaceTextWithParameters:(NSArray*)parameters {
    if([self.yourText isEqualToString:[parameters objectAtIndex:0]) {
        self.yourText = [parameters objectAtIndex:1];
    }
}
```

Then you would only have to call :

```
NSArray *parameterArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Text to search", @"replacementText", nil];
[yourArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(replaceTextWithParameters:) withObject:parameterArray];
```

It would be a lot faster at run time than looping on each element of your array (especially if you have many elements)

Comment: I edited my answer with a sample to give you the idea (untested)

Comment: @vdaubry `makeObjectsPerformSelector` *does* perform a loop. There is no difference.

Comment: Actually it seems that this answer states that makeObjectsPerformSelector is faster than custom loop : I haven't benched it but it seems reasonable that Apple implementation is the most optimized : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582521/cocoa-nsarray-nsset-makeobjectsperformselector-vs-fast-enumeration

Comment: @vdaubry You're splitting hairs. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Agree. If he has no performance issue with this loop I would recommend reddexuk to go with the implementation he feels the most confortable with.